# Inserting mathematical equations in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to generate a report which should contain a set of different mathematical equations. I need a way to inserted in my report, there's no condition on the way one can represent the equations so any solution will do, either if the equations come in latex format or MathML or whatever. Is there a way to do it or do I have to insert the equations as Images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still fairly new to Jasper Reports, but I believe you will have to insert images of the equations into your report (just like how Wikipedia uses images for their equations).

[How to Show an Image on Jasper Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746561/how-to-show-an-image-on-jasper-report)

Comment: I was afraid I would need that. Thanks anyway