# JasperReports: Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name

Tags: java, jasper-reports, glassfish-3

I am currently working on a project with jasper reports, netbeans 7.1.1, and Glassfish server. It seems that report with image runs on a Jasper successfully but when I run through my web application, exception has thrown as `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name`.

```
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:460)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:146)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:385)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1003)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:998)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.APIClassLoaderServiceImpl$APIClassLoader.getResource(APIClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:998)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:998)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1153)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRResourcesUtil.findClassLoaderResource(JRResourcesUtil.java:473)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadBytesFromLocation(JRLoader.java:464)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getInstance(JRImageRenderer.java:176)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:944)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:891)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:256)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:482)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2011)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:603)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeaders(JRVerticalFiller.java:523)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:250)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:110)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:923)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:826)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:59)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:247)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:203)
at org.serv.ReportServlet.generateReport(ReportServlet.java:142)
at org.serv.ReportServlet.doPost(ReportServlet.java:86)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
```

Can anyone help me please

Comment: could you please post the stacktrace. It make us to help you better.

Comment: Can you show us the image path you used in your jrxml. This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746561/how-to-show-an-image-on-jasper-report

Comment: Just been hit by something similar with the same exception message, the problem turned out to be a mistake in the classpath the webapp classpath loader was being passed.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the call to getResource on the ClasssLoader with a try/catch block:

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = loader.getResource(fileName);
} catch (final Exception e) {
}
```

After that statement the url is checked for a null value and if it's null you already try to create a `java.io.File` object of the *fileName*. Maybe it's even a better solution to first check if the passed fileName is a valid File and only ask the ClassLoader for an URL if it's not an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same Exception but was sending an invalid character(i.e., '_') in my data map for one of the fields, the issue was resolved after I removed the underscore from my data.

**error that I was seeing:**
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character: _

Please check if you've sent invalid characters for the 'name' field.