# How to send an image?

Tags: image, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have no idea. There is no such option. The image comes from unknown source.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear what are you trying to do, this? [How to show an image on jasper report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746561/how-to-show-an-image-on-jasper-report). You need to explain more if not, unknown source?, you need to know something, url?, file?, stream?..

Answer (score 2):

Add an image element to your report

[image: Image element]

---

Then click **OK**

[image: New image dialog]

---

Create a new parameter for *LOGO* with class "java.awt.Image". **It isn't listed in the ComboBox, you have to write it yourself**

[image: Parameter]

---

Click on the image element and add the new parameter into the parameter expression

[image: Image element properties]

---

And finally pass an image in your code to the report

```
reportParams.put("LOGO", YourImageObjectHere);
```

Comment: Why do you suggest "java.awt.Image"?, I mean the choice of class to use depends on application, anyway nice post that explains how to do it in JasperStudio, maybe I would have posted it on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746561/how-to-show-an-image-on-jasper-report instead (without a direct suggestion about what class to choose), I edited the question with studio tag to better honor your answer (not sure what to do with the title of question however, send??.."